# Setting byte array pointer in structure in C

Tags: c, struct, malloc, arrays

I have a structure that contains a pointer to a byte array.

To set the pointer I’ve tried the following two ways:

1 Use malloc then memcpy byte array data (commented out in code below).

2 Simply copy pointer.

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"

typedef struct _element
{
    unsigned char *pValue;
    int nLength;
} Element;

Element* ElementCreate(void)
{
    Element *pElement = (Element*)malloc(sizeof(*pElement));

    pElement->pValue = NULL;
    pElement->nLength = 0;

    return pElement;
}

void ElementDestroy(Element **ppElement)
{
    Element *pElement = NULL;

    if (!ppElement)
        return;

    pElement = *ppElement;

    //free(pElement->pValue);
    //pElement->pValue = NULL;

    free(pElement);
    *ppElement = NULL;
}

void ElementSetValue(Element *pElement, unsigned char *pValue, int nLength)
{
    //pElement->pValue = (unsigned char*)malloc(nLength * sizeof(*(pElement->pValue)));
    //if (!(pElement->pValue))
    //    return;

    //memcpy(pElement->pValue, pValue, nLength);

    pElement->pValue = pValue;
    pElement->nLength = nLength;
}

void ElementWriteValue(const Element *pElement)
{
    int nIndex = 0;
    for (; nIndex < pElement->nLength; nIndex++)
        printf("%02X ", pElement->pValue[nIndex]);
}

int main(void)
{
    //unsigned char myValue[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };
    //int nLength = sizeof(myValue) / sizeof(myValue[0]);

    Element *pElement = ElementCreate();

    {
        unsigned char myValue[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };
        int nLength = sizeof(myValue) / sizeof(myValue[0]);

        ElementSetValue(pElement, myValue, nLength);
    }

    // How come this writes out correct value?
    ElementWriteValue(pElement);

    ElementDestroy(&pElement);

    return 0;
}
```

(Error checks are omitted for brevity)

Which way is correct?

I’d expect 2 to fail because myValue will be destroyed after the “}” so

```
printf("%02X ", pElement->pValue[nIndex]);
```

would write out rubbish data but it seems to work OK.  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is undefined behaviour, of which a subset is to "work correctly".

The array `myValue` is out of scope at the next `}`. At this point the memory location in which `myValue` was stored is available to be resused, but it may not be leaving it unchanged and hence the code appears to work.

The correct approach is to `malloc()`, `memcpy()` and `free()`.

Answer (score 0):

when we enter into

```
{
    unsigned char myValue[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };
    int nLength = sizeof(myValue) / sizeof(myValue[0]);

    ElementSetValue(pElement, myValue, nLength);
}
```

that mean a memory will be reserved for myValue. and when we leave it (after `}`) that mean the memory related to myValue is not reserved any more and it's free but the content is not changed. and that's why you have access to memory and its content is not changed.
If your application is multithread application then there is a big risk that the data related to myValue meory changes by another thread and in this case you have always access to the same memory space but you will find that the memory content changes